# react-native app lags on android

Tags: android, react-native

I wrote simple app on react-native. It consists of `<ListView>` that shows `<Image>` in rows. Images are fetched from the network. It runs on iOS very well. But on Android if stucks when image appears. FPS is 0.9-3.2;
I used systrace tool to figure out what is going on. Here is a  screenshot of it.

[image]

It looks like everything is done on UI thread.

Here is a render function of my class:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ListView
                style={styles.list}
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
                />
        </View>
    );
}

renderRow(rowData) {
    return <Image
      style={{ width: 320, height: 320 }}
      source={{uri: rowData.coverPhoto}} />
}
```

I have aa filling that I missed something. Can somebody help me figure out what exactly ?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to track down if the issue is hardware-related?

Comment: I've tried to set `renderToHardwareTextureAndroid` to `true` but it did not halped

Comment: But could it be related to the processing power of either of the devices? You did not say what Android/iPhone you tested it on. You should determine if the issue is related to the device specifications or the ReactAndroid project.

Comment: I tried to run this app on SGS4 and Nexus 5. It works the same on both devices. So I don't think it is doe to device performance. Due to systrace it's obvious that lags are caused by performing to much on UI thread.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem recently and figured out what's causing this and how to solve it (at least for me). I know this is old, but I'll leave this here in case somebody needs it.

**The Cause**

For me it was the image from the net. Its resolution is huge (more than 3000x4000) while my `<Image />` component was styled to be small (50x50 to be exact).

**The Solution**

There's a prop for `<Image />` specifically for Android, which is `resizeMethod` (this is different from `resizeMode`). I used `resizeMethod: resize` and the app runs well on Android. Here's the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#resizemethod) for more info.

Answer (score -2):

Try change

```
 renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
```

to

```
renderRow={this.renderRow}
```